# Are ID of default fields same for SharePoint installed on different machines?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, guid

Are ID of default fields (or SharePoint components) in 14 hive same for SharePoint installed on different machines ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the Guid of the default fields like `Title`, `Author`, `Created` etc. stays the same across machines. You can reference them with the [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid_members.aspx) class. E.g.: `SPBuiltInFieldId.Title` will give you the Guid of the Title field.

Comment: I am using CAML query to define content type and I am referring 
`14-Hive\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\fields\fieldswss.xml` for refering existing columns.

Comment: Yes the GUIDs mentioned in that file are common across different machines too. In fact if you fetch the GUID of a default column through the `SPBuiltInFieldId` class, it will return the same GUID as mentioned in the `fieldswee.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

This link shows SharePoint Default field GUID(ID), Internal Name and Display Name..

http://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/sharepoint-internal-field-names-sharepoint-2010/

and this GUIDs are not changed in any system. They remains same.